# logback's replace feature doesn't support greater than or less than sign (<>) in the pattern

Tags: replace, logback

We want to use the replace feature of logback http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#replace. It works for the example described in the documentation. However, it does not work if there's > or < sign in the pattern. For example, something like the following

```
<pattern>%replace(%m){"pswd='.*'", "pswd='<xxx'"}%n</pattern>
```

generates the following exception

> XML_PARSING - Parsing fatal error on line 14 and column 298
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 298;
>   Element type "xxx" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>".  at org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:
>   Element type "xxx" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>".

We need to be able to have < or > in the pattern because our data is going to be of the form

```
<password>1234</password>
```

and we want to be able to replace it with `<password>xxx</password>`.

We have also tried escaping the < (i.e. \<) with the same result. Is there something we are missing or is this a known issue? Any work around?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do the following:

```
<pattern>%replace(%m){"pswd='.*'", "pswd='&lt;xxx'"}%n</pattern>
```

Comment: Yes it's an XML encoding issue.